# Visual studio code: Cannot build install project with python extension enabled

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

I have a workspace setup in visual studio code where I develop one c++ project (that also swig generates python bindings). And one python project that uses these python bindings.

When I make a change to the c++ project and build it everything works nice. But when I build the install project, that copies the .dlls etc. to the installed directory I get an error message that tells me that I cant copy the dlls since they are already in use.

If I disable the python extension everything works fine. I guess that the extension uses the dlls for intellisense and auto-completion.

This results in that I have to disable the python extension and reload vscode every time I want to build the install project. Is there any other way to handle this?

I use vscode version 1.23.1 on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that Jedi is opening the DLLs for Intellisense and then not releasing the files in a way that makes Windows happy.

We are working on bringing the language server from Visual Studio over and it may operate differently enough to not cause you this issue. Keep an eye on https://aka.ms/pythonblog for when we make it available.

Comment: Do you have any time estimation on that release?

Comment: We have a policy not to share time estimates on anything since they can easily slip. The hope is a public preview soon, though.